# Export multiple images from a directory to one Excel worksheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, image, export

I would like to export images from an image folder to Excel with all images on one worksheet. I have managed to export an image but only one image. This is my code:

```
public void ExportToExcel()
    {
        //for export
        ExcelPackage objExcelPackage = new ExcelPackage();   //create new workbook

        string[] filesindirectory = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Image"));
        int count = 0;

        ExcelWorksheet ws = objExcelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Worksheet" + count); //create new worksheet

                    foreach (string img in filesindirectory)
                    {
                    count++;
                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image TEST_IMAGE = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
                    System.Drawing.Image myImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(img);
                    var pic = ws.Drawings.AddPicture(count.ToString(), myImage);
                    // Row, RowoffsetPixel, Column, ColumnOffSetPixel
                    pic.SetPosition(1, 0, 2, 0);
                        }
                }                            
        var filepath = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test\" + datetime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_hh-mm-ss") + ".xlsx");
        objExcelPackage.SaveAs(filepath);
    }
```

This is the output I want to achieve:

[image]

How to export all images from a directory to Excel in one Excel worksheet using EPPlus?

Comment: First at all not 1 image... is imported all but all stack on it...
To do you need to modify your `pic.SetPosition` to have dynamic rows...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy way to pull this off is using your variable `count`

```
int x = 8;
int finalValue = 0;

if (count > 1) {
    pic.SetPosition(finalValue , 0, 2, 0);
    finalValue += (x + 1); // Add 1 to have 1 row of empty row
}
else {
    pic.SetPosition(count, 0, 2, 0);
    finalValue = (count + x) + 1; // Add 1 to have 1 row of empty
}
```

x is depend on your image size of row.

For example your image use 8 row for 1 image 
But anyway you can actually set the image size in your code.. 
It will be easier for you to control the row

Comment: hi @Nic, thanks I have tried your method and it works! :) Do you know how I can set the image size? thanks for your help!

Comment: @FeliciaSoh using `pic.SetSize` but the width and height u need to ensure it

Comment: Hi @Nic, do you know how can I set the image position in decimal like 1.5px? Something like pic.SetPosition  (1.5, 0, 14, 0)?

Comment: @FeliciaSoh I'm not so sure about it.. maybe you can try it ?

Comment: I tried with the method pic.SetPosition (1.5, 0, 14, 0) but got error becos this method only accepts integer values. Never mind I think of other workarounds. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Nic Thnaks for your reply here and your solution working very well.  One more point I want to know here is that, How can I set image height & width in cell??